# Create a console application to read data from Azure Table Storage using C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

Please suggest good documentations on creating a console application for reading data from Azure Table Storage. I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z96fIv3RQBo and created a sample console application as follows. On running the console, I see 'ReceivedBadRequest' error:

```
class Program
    {
        const string StorageAccountName = "";
        const string StorageAccountKey = "";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(StorageAccountName, StorageAccountKey), false);
            var tableaa = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference("Table1");
            var result = tableaa.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Retrieve<Person>("<partition-key>", "<row-key>"));
            var entity = result.Result;
            Console.WriteLine(entity);
        }
    }

    class Person : TableEntity
    {
        private int customerID;
        private string LocationAreaCode;
        private string PersonnelSubAreaCode;
        private string PersonStatusCode;
        public void AssignRowKey()
        {
            this.RowKey = customerID.ToString();
        }
        public void AssignPartitionKey()
        {
            this.PartitionKey = "<partition-key";
        }    
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` you are using?

Comment: Have a look of this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-table-dotnet?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#get-an-entity-from-a-partition Does this help?

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS Partition Key value is PersonnelNumber. RowKey is random guid value (autogenerated)

Comment: I would recommend tracings your request/response through Fiddler. That should give you more information about the error you’re getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an parameter-less constructor in your Person class:

Please change the Person class as below:

```
class Person : TableEntity
{
    private int customerID;
    private string LocationAreaCode;
    private string PersonnelSubAreaCode;
    private string PersonStatusCode;

    public Person()
    {

    }

    //other code


}
```

For more details, please refer to this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-table-dotnet?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#define-the-entity).

Comment: This is definitely a problem but I highly doubt that it will give `BadRequest` error.

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS, thanks for pointing this out. Let's wait the the op's feedback by adding this and see if he needs further help.

Comment: The doc talks about Azure Cosmos DB Table API. I'm looking for Azure Table Storage?

Comment: @user3693060, Azure Cosmos DB Table API is absolutely can be used for azure table storage  and it's recommended:).

Comment: I’m looking for reading data from table in storage account. Could you please share any doc related to that? Thank you!

Comment: @user3693060, yes, the completed official doc is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-table-dotnet?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json), please follow the doc to install any nuget packages necessary.

Comment: For read data, you should first [Define the entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-table-dotnet?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#define-the-entity). Remember that the parameter-less constructor is a must.

Comment: Then follow [Get an entity from a partition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-table-dotnet?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#get-an-entity-from-a-partition) to read the data you need.

Comment: @user3693060, please let me know if you have any issues about that. Read data from table storage is not hard:)

Comment: @IvanYang Thank you so much. These steps worked. Curious to know if Azure Table Storage is same as Azure Cosmos DB Table API. I'm storing data in a table in storage account and the code in the doc is describing how to create table in cosmos db. Please let me know.

Comment: @user3693060, I see you asked another question about that, do you still need I follow up the questions in this thread?

Comment: @IvanYang I've closed that question. Hoping to continue on this thread. I was able to query by using LINQ. I'm trying to query by using OData filter. Could you please provide some examples on the same (in c#)?

Comment: @user3693060, if you want to use OData filter, I suggest raise a new issue(because this is a different thing compared to this thread, and will make others confused.), and then let me know the url of the new question:).

Comment: @IvanYang Thank you. Please see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61925442/how-to-query-a-table-using-odata-filter-in-c-sharp

Comment: @user3693060, I see. I will post an answer when I figure it out:).

Comment: @IvanYang Thank you so much, appreciate your help!

Comment: @IvanYang could you please let me know how to read more than 1000 rows from Azure Table Storage?