# Console app to use azure storage tableapi

Tags: c#, httpclient, azure-table-storage

Please provide some examples (console application) on sending http request to query an azure table storage using OData?

Comment: Although the official SDK uses linq to query data. But I think in my answer, calling rest api in the background service is also a better solution. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You can find your `sastoken` at portal like my pic.

And u also need to update the value of `x-ms-date`(*Required. Specifies the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) for the request.*) in `HttpHelper` file .

For more details, you can download [my demo](https://github.com/Jason446620/ConsoleProj) code in github( You can download my `HttpHelper` file).

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static ODatafilter.HttpHelper;

namespace ODatafilter
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Azure Cosmos Table Samples");
            string baseurl = @"https://panshubeistorage.table.core.windows.net/";
            string tbname = "People";//Console.ReadLine();
            string sastoken = @"?sv=2019-10-10&ss=************";
            string filter = @"&$filter=PartitionKey%20eq%20'Smith'%20";
            baseurl = baseurl + tbname + "()" + sastoken+filter;
            HttpResponseData data = HttpHelper.GetForOData(baseurl);
            string responseData = data.Data.Replace(".","_");
            ODataResponse odata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ODataResponse>(responseData);

            foreach (ODatavalue m in odata.value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.PartitionKey + "    " + m.PhoneNumber + "    " + m.RowKey + "   " + m.Email);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.Read();
        }
        public class ODataResponse
        {
            public string odata_metadata { get; set; }
            public List<ODatavalue> value { get; set; }
        }
        public class ODatavalue {
            public string odata_type { get; set; }
            public string odata_id { get; set; }
            public string odata_etag { get; set; }
            public string odata_editLink { get; set; }
            public string Timestamp { get; set; }
            public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
            public string RowKey { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

**PRIVIOUS**

You can use LinQ to query like the document like you supported.

[image]

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Azure Cosmos Table Samples");
        Console.WriteLine("Query data by filter");

        CloudTable table = GetTable();

        Console.WriteLine("pls input PartitionKey:");
        string PartitionKey = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("pls input RowKey:");
        string RowKey = Console.ReadLine();
        //Query
        IQueryable<CustomerEntity> linqQuery = table.CreateQuery<CustomerEntity>()
        .Where(x => x.PartitionKey== PartitionKey && x.RowKey== RowKey)
        .Select(x => new CustomerEntity() { PartitionKey = x.PartitionKey, RowKey = x.RowKey, Email = x.Email, PhoneNumber= x.PhoneNumber });

        var list = linqQuery.ToList<CustomerEntity>();

        foreach (CustomerEntity m in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.PartitionKey+"    "+m.PhoneNumber+"    "+m.RowKey+"   "+m.Email);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static CloudTable GetTable() {
        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=***x=core.windows.net");
        CloudTableClient tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("People");
        return table;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know how to query using LINQ. I'm trying to understand how to query using OData filter. Please let me know if you have any idea on that. Thanks!

Comment: @user3693060 If I use HttpClient in my consoledemo to request something like `https: // <mytableapi-endpoint> / People () ?$filter=PartitionKey%20eq%20'Smith'%20and%20Email%20eq%20'Ben@contoso.com '`, Is this what you want?

Comment: @user3693060 The documentation is very clear, we can query the data through oData's REST and SDK. The filter in oData has nothing to do with the SDK.

Comment: @user3693060 Send Http request in the code, I think this sub-operation can reduce the time of our server for data processing and sorting, and the code is much simpler.

Comment: thank you so much. You are correct: if I use 'https://<mytableapi-endpoint>/ People()?$filter=PartitionKey%20eq%20'Smith'%20and%20Email%20eq%20'Ben@contoso.com ', I should see output. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: I see that you have declared all the members in CustomerEntity class in ODatavalue class and use that as return type. Is it possible to avoid this and use CustomerEntity as the return type? Please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214365/discussion-between-user3693060-and-jason).

Comment: You should pay attention to the format of the response returned by the tableapi interface. All I did was deserialize the returned string into an object. You can flexibly modify according to your project needs. @user3693060

Comment: Could you please let me know how to read more than 1000 rows from Azure Table Storage? Right now I only see 1000 rows being returned. Appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: @user989988 I will  check the documents on Monday to deal with the problem.

Comment: @user989988 The answer in your post is correct. You just need to find `NextPartitionKey`  
 and `NextRowKey`, pls read offical doc.