# Convert data in table storage from string to other formats in .NET SDK

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to convert data in table storage from string format to int/timestamp format in .NET SDK?

I used an ADF pipeline to copy data from data lake to blob storage and then from blob storage to table storage. After running pipeline, I see all columns in table storage in string format.

I need to use the following query to filter data in table:

```
https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/Customers()?$filter=Age%20gt%2030
```

Currently this doesn't work as the data in Age column is in string format.

Is it possible to first convert the data in 'Age' column to integer format and use the above query?

Comment: How would converting age to integer help? How would you convert it? And the moment you convert it, it will already be obsolete since time moves forward. Shouldn't you be storing date of birth instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know why you are obsessed with this question. As you asked in another post, Leon’s answer clearly tells you that it is not feasible.

Now I complete the whole operation by reading the data in the original table, creating a new table, and inserting the data, I hope it helps you. You can download [my demo](https://github.com/Jason446620/cosmos-tablecopy), just need to replace your `StorageConnectionString` in Settings.json.

You need create table Customer.[More details you can see source code.]

Then run, you can see new table created from Storage Explorer, and data in there.

[image]

If you want [filter data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61925442/console-app-to-use-azure-storage-tableapi/61929744#61929744), you can do it.

[image]