# HTTPWebResponse "GET" API Call Exception - C#

Tags: c#, http

I'm attempting to access a remote API and I'm getting a few exceptions during the HTTPWebResponse call. Below is my code:

```
//url
string responseValue = string.Empty;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.someapi.com")
request.Method = "GET";
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
request.Headers("x-ms-client-id", "data");

try{
    using (var response = (HttpWebRequest)req.GetResponse()){ <--- this line is the one that fails. System.IO.IOException here.
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream()){
            using(var sr = new StreamReader(stream)){
                responseValue = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
} catch ///catch
```

The errors I'm getting are SocketExceptions and WebExceptions. I'm not sure why this specific call is failing. When I attempt the same URL and headers in Postman, the call returns a 200.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Adding the error messages I'm getting. The exception being thrown when the response is attempted is

```
System.IO.IOException: "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."
```

Comment: What is the full error message you get ?

Comment: Is this your code choice for calling an api, or are you on a legacy version of .NET Framework?

Comment: use `HttpClient` .. this WebRequest stuff is old-school.

Comment: Yes, this is calling an API. The project is targeting the 4.5.2 .net framework.

Comment: You should name the scheme in the uri. Presumably your making a http call to a https endpoint. And HttpClient exists in the 4.5 framework.

Comment: The default HTTP headers in c# are different from Postman.  For example the UserAgent which is the default browser may be different (see  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent?force_isolation=true).  You cold be using HTTPS (secure) and the TLS authentication could be failing. More than likely it is a TLS issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, I often use `HttpWebRequest`  like below code.

[You can download the HttpHelper](https://github.com/Jason446620/ConsoleProj/blob/master/ODatafilter/HttpHelper.cs) I compiled and call it according to my reference example, or you can add Http Header as required.

***How to invoke HttpHelper, ex: Get Method***

[Console app to use azure storage tableapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61925442/console-app-to-use-azure-storage-tableapi/61929744#61929744)

```
String PostParam = String.Empty;
if (Data != null)
{
    PostParam = Data.ToString();//Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data);
}
byte[] postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PostParam);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url + (Id == null ? "" : '/' + Id.ToString())));
request.Method = Method;
request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
request.Timeout = HttpRequestTimeOut;
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
if (postData.Length > 0)
{
    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
         requestStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
    }
}
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    Response.Code = response.StatusCode;
    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
         Response.Data = stream.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```